# Disable contact sync for one Google account - S8 - Android 8

Tags: sync, google-account, 8.0-oreo, google-contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-8

My Samsung Glaxy S8 with Android 8.0 & Samsung Experience 9, is configured with multiple Google accounts. Would like to disable contact sync for only one Google account, **while synchronising all Google accounts calendars**, including the account with contact sync disabled

Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can choose what items to sync in the account settings. The option might be relocated slightly, but you'll ideally find it at the following location. I'm including a screenshot for reference.

*Settings > Users & Accounts > **Your Google Account** > Account sync*.

Here turn off the toggle for Contacts.

[image]

Contacts from this account will stop syncing while from all other accounts will continue to sync. The calendar functionality will not be impacted unless you disable that as well.

Comment: Thanks mate. Contacts are still visible in the phone, may I proceed to deletion?

Comment: @Riccardo Already synced contacts from that Google account will continue to show on the device. You can delete them from the device and they will go away without affecting the cloud version. Or if all of your Contacts come from cloud and not stored in the phone storage, then it's better to clear the data of contacts storage system app. This will remove all contacts from the phone and then the accounts which are set to sync will return back and contacts from this disabled Google account will not.